# IPhone App provisioning in XCode - No "Build and Go" button

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I am trying to get an iPhone app packaged up. (I'm very new to Mac and iPhone development, so please explain any instructions you give in detail.)

I'm following the directions on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action).

Under "Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution", I'm having issues. The first issue is that it told me to duplicate the release configuration and name it "distribution", but I accidentally deleted the release configuration (the delete button is right next to duplicate!) Can I just duplicate the debug build or is there a way to restore the release configuration?

If I proceed by duplicating the debug configuration as distribution, I then get stuck on step 7, which has you set the Active SDK to an iPhone Device. I don't have any "Active SDK" option in my dropdown, the top item is just "Device" and then in the "Active Executable" section it has a bunch of simulators but no iPhone devices. The last issue, which must be related to this, is that there is no Build and Go button in the toolbar, there is only Build and Run (for running the simulator.)

Comment: There's always a way to restore a file to a pre-existing state: `svn/git/hg revert Foo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`. You *are* using version control, aren't you?

Comment: In my version of Xcode (3.2.3) the "Build and Go" button is now called "Build and Run". I think the tutorial just hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but you cannot just duplicate debug configuration as release - unless you are an expert in compiler settings.

In short debug configuration creates a bigger and slower application containing lots of debug information, which is unnecessary (or even security risk) for release. Vice versa release configuration removes those, optimizes performance and creates universal binary. It's not really as simple as that, but hope you see the difference.

My advice in this case, since you say you're "very new to to Mac and iPhone development": **create a new project and copy all your files** from current project to the new.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to recreate the project and get the Release configuration back. However the main issue is that under Active SDK's I only have simulators, how do I get the options like "Device - iPhone OS 2.0", "Device - iPhone OS 2.1", etc... I've already tried reinstalling the iOS SDK and xTools but it didn't change anything.